# Install for Azure Storage Explorer on Mac (Catalina) is not working

Tags: macos, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I am trying to install the Azure Storage Explorer on my Mac (MacOS Catalina, Version 10.15.1). As per this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=macos#prerequisites), this seems to be supported.

However, after downloading (v.1.11.1), I got this error message:

**"Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.**

*This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue is coming because of [`notarization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution?preferredLanguage=occ) restriction Apple has put on new Mac apps.

Best place to raise this issue on the Azure Storage Explorer Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks,

Comment: BTW, I reached out to MSFT folks involved with Storage Explorer and made them aware of this issue.

Comment: There is an issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/2395